# 空白文字を含むパスをsubprocess.Popenで開く際のエラー

Tags: python

次の①、②のようなコードを使ってsubprocess.Popenを使用するとエラーが出ます。ディレクトリ名に「Test App」と空白文字列が入っていることが原因かと思われますが、ディレクトリ名を変更する以外の方法だと、どうすれば正しく実行できそうですか？

①パスをそのまま使用した場合(test1.py)

```
import os
import subprocess
appData_installerPath = ""
appDataPath = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'),'Test App')
appData_installerPath = os.path.join(appDataPath,'test.exe')
subprocess.Popen(appData_installerPath,shell=True)
```

test1.pyを実行した場合のエラーメッセージ

```
'C:\Users\taichi\AppData\Roaming\Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

②repr()でraw文字列に変換して試した場合(test2.py)

```
import os
import subprocess
appData_installerPath = ""
appDataPath = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'),'Test App')
appData_installerPath = os.path.join(appDataPath,'test.exe')
subprocess.Popen(repr(appData_installerPath),shell=True)
```

test2.pyを実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: 似た環境で実行ファイルをおいた状態でPythonスクリプトを実行する限りでは実行ファイルの起動が動作するようです。また、実行ファイルが存在しない状態だと同様のメッセージが出ます。そのため、まずは生成されたフルパスに実行ファイルが存在すのかの確認をしてみたほうが良いかもしれません。

Comment: Pythonに限らずWindowsでは空白を含むパスはダブルクォーテーションで囲むのが通常です。[長いファイル名またはスペースを含むパスには引用符が必要です](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/filenames-with-spaces-require-quotation-mark), [Windows でパスに空白を含むときの回避策](https://garapon.hatenablog.com/entry/20080124/1201149409) あるいは`shell=True`を外すのが良いかもしれません。[Popen コンストラクター](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) `Windows で shell=True を指定する必要があるのは、実行したいコマンドがシェルに組み込みの場合だけです`